# How to clone all the account of a given slot?

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator, account-data

How could I download all the accounts at a given slot. Like Snapshot of all the Solana accounts at a recent given slot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what format you'd be looking for, but you can create snapshots at specific slots with `solana-ledger-tool create-snapshot`. This subcommand works by unpacking a snapshot, verifying blocks to advance state to desired slot (specified by command line argument), and then saving the state (ie all accounts) to a new snapshot.

In order to create a snapshot at slot `S` with this tool, you will need two things:

- A snapshot at some slot `L` where `L < S`
- The blocks between `L` and `S`

Based on your question, I'd recommend running `solana-ledger-tool --help`, and running `--help` on specific subcommands too just to familiarize yourself with what all is in there.